# Angular Module with Multiple Component Gets Slow in loading

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-template

I have found a scenario which delays initiating my module in Angular 2.
I am not an experienced guy in Angular. This is my first project. So, didn't know how to deal with this scenario:

I have created a small application in which there are various modules. Each module has 2-3 subcomponents. But my SignUp Module and MyAccount Module is the mixture of various components.

Below is the hierarchy of my application.

> app
>   --Front-end
>   ----videos
>   ------Detail
>   --------videodetail.component.html
>   --------videodetail.component.ts
>   ------List
>   --------list.component.html
>   --------list.component.ts
>   ------videos.component.html
>   ------videos.component.ts
>   ------videos.routing.ts
>   ------videos.module.ts
>   ----article
>   ------article.component.html
>   ------article.component.ts
>   ----front-end.routing.ts
>   ----front-end.module.ts
>   ----front-end.component.ts
>   ----front-end.component.html
>   --signup
>   ----stepone
>   ------stepone.component.html
>   ------stepone.component.ts
>   ----steptwo
>   ------steptwo.component.html
>   ------steptwo.component.ts
>   ----stepthree
>   ------stepthree.component.html
>   ------stepthree.component.ts
>   ----stepfour
>   ------stepfour.component.html
>   ------stepfour.component.ts
>   ----final
>   ------final.component.html
>   ------final.component.ts
>   ----OneMore
>   ------onemore.component.html
>   ------onemore.component.ts
>   ----signup.module.ts
>   ----signup.component.ts
>   ----signup.routing.ts
>   ----signup.component.html   app.module.ts    app.component.ts   app.component.html   app.routing.ts

Below is the `signup-routing.module.ts` routing code for children.

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: SignupComponent },
    { path: 'terms', component: TermsComponent },
    { path: 'first', component: StepOneComponent },
    { path: 'second', component: SteptwoComponent },
    { path: 'third', component: StepthreeComponent },
    { path: 'third/:status', component: StepthreeComponent },
    { path: 'third/:status/:type', component: StepthreeComponent },
    { path: 'success', component: FinalComponent }
```

As requested, below is the constructor of `SingupComponent` and `BaseComponent`.

```
export class BaseComponent implements OnInit  {
    public SiteConfigurations: SiteConfigurations;
    public options: any
    constructor() {
        this.SiteConfigurations = new SiteConfigurations();
        var currentClass= this;
        window["SetDefaultImage"] = function(){}
        window["SetDefaultImage"]=function (event){
          currentClass.SetDefaultImageWithCurrentClass(event,currentClass);
        };
    }

    ngOnInit() {
      //  this.options = Baser
    }

    SetDefaultImageWithCurrentClass(event,currentClass) {
        event.target.src = currentClass.SiteConfigurations.EnvironmentConfigurations.siteURL+"assets/images/no-image.png";
    }
    SetDefaultImage(event) {
      this.SetDefaultImageWithCurrentClass(event,this);
    }
}

export class SignupComponent extends BaseComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
constructor(router: Router, accountService: AccountService) {
    super();
    this.accountService = accountService;
    this.router = router; }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.packageType = this.getStepData("packageType");
        this.stepone = this.getStepData("stepone");
        this.steptwo = this.getStepData("steptwo");

        this.options = this.accountService.notificationService.options;
        this.clear = true;
    }
}
```

Below is my `app-routing.module.ts` code.

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '', component: FrontEndComponent,
        children: [
        { path: 'home', loadChildren: './home/home.module#HomeModule' },
        { path: 'videos', loadChildren: './videos/videos.module#VideosModule' },
        { path: 'myaccount', loadChildren: './users/users.module#UsersModule', canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
        { path: 'signup', loadChildren: '../signup/signup.module#SignupModule' }]   
    } 
];
```

When I run my application and homepage gets loaded, when I click on SignUp for the first time it takes some time to execute the constructor of the signup.component.ts 
The reason I found is in the signup module there are various subcomponents which get load when the signup module is called for the first time (i.e. when the chunk file is generated). The same problem is with the AccountModule where around 8 to 10 subcomponents are used to show data in the user account dashboard.

It holds for some 2-3 seconds before the SignUp component's constructor and onInit method is called and then go to the server side to take data from the database.
While other modules like videos, articles and rest other have only 2 and maximum 3 subcomponents and they are getting executed immediately.

Comment: can you post the constructor of  `SignupComponent`?

Comment: I have updated by description and added code for signup and basecomponent constructor. getStepdata is the local client function it doesn't go to the server side.

Comment: Try `{ path: '', component: SignupComponent,pathMatch: 'full' },`

Comment: Yes, Tried But no Luck . Stil the same. 
Problem is chunk file gets time to revert back. If I commented out the html portion from the two component then it will be fast enough. But thats not a solution. We can have a module with couple of more component in that case we need some way to deal with that.

Comment: Hi, do you use webpack to buld and watch the changes? as my project, the workflow like this (in development) I change code -> save -> webpack automatically build, it take 3-4 seconds. After successful build, It also auto reload my page. 
if you also use some kind of tool like webpack (to build) then I think this is normal, because it has to re-build, now or later, like right after I save or when you re-load the page.
and again this is development, so this is totally okay! hope this help~

Comment: @PrashantKankhara did u find any solution?

Answer (score 4):

figure out what is wrong in your application without accessing the codebase is not easy, but I try the same giving some good advice that could help you.

### Use @angular/cli

I've known many people that refused the use of a build tool, because *webpack* is already able to perform optimizations and uglifications if properly configured, but those people can't imagine how much powerful is this command:

```
ng build --prod
```

It will:

1. Compile your code **Ahead Of Time** (AOT)
2. Set the `production` flag
3. Hash the name of the files (to prevent caching)
4. Not produce sourcemaps
5. Optimize your code (from **Angular 5**)
6. Run **UglifyJS** on the code

So if you don't use **@angular/cli**, start using it. If you use it but you still didn't update your version, then update it.

### Use source-map-explorer

[source-map-explorer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/source-map-explorer) is a tool that let you know where the weight of your files come from. Maybe you imported a whole library but you just needed few functions? You can discover it through this tool.

### Chrome is your friend

Another powerful tool which is often ignored is the **Chrome Developer Tool**. You don't need to install anything, just press `F12`, click on the *Performance* tab and [start profiling](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/rendering-tools/).

Maybe you used a heavy sync function that's slowing down all the application? Maybe there's a function that needs some optimization? You can discover it, after your profiling you can see where your application takes more time, and clicking on the *Call tree* tab you can discover what's the name of that function and what's the source.

For similar purposes you can also check [webpagetest.org](https://www.webpagetest.org/).

### Use a service worker

A well known way to speed up your application is using a service worker. You can read an interesting article clicking [here](https://stormpath.com/blog/progressive-web-applications-angular-spring-boot-stormpath).

The idea is to apply the [PRPL pattern](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/prpl-pattern/) to Angular (which is a pattern that aims to optimize the parsing and the executation in order to achieve interactivity in low times through aggressive code-splitting and caching).

I hope some of my hints could lead you in the right direction. Let me know about it

Comment: Great Explanation, I will go through and let you know if anyhow it helps to load the chunk fast.

Answer (score 1):

Please read and understand about angular lazy loading. Following links may help you to solve your problem.

https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/how-to-lazy-load-components-in-angular-4-in-three-steps/

https://medium.com/@leekp/lazy-loading-with-angular-4-29c23792b7f4

https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/modules/lazy-loading-module.html

As I can see your solution has routing for each modules. You must load them as follows on app-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'signup', loadChildren: 'sighup/sighup.module#SignUpModule' },
  { path: 'front-end', loadChildren: 'front-end/front-end.module#FrontEndModule' },

];
```

This will prevent executing other modules when calling signup module.

Than signup routing can change as follows also. (it depends on your application)

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: SignupComponent },
children: [
    { path: 'terms', component: TermsComponent },
    { path: 'first', component: StepOneComponent },
    { path: 'second', component: SteptwoComponent },
    { path: 'third', component: StepthreeComponent },
    { path: 'third/:status', component: StepthreeComponent },
    { path: 'third/:status/:type', component: StepthreeComponent },
    { path: 'success', component: FinalComponent }
]
}
```

also set for sign up module in signup.components.html too.

Comment: thanks for the solution.I tried this but No luck again. Its taking same time whether for this too.

Comment: As I understand when the Signup Component is loading components of other modules also loading. Are all components have imports in app.module.ts or other module.ts files ?

Comment: No, When signup loads components of other modules are not getting load but the components of signupmodule are getting load when the "chunk.js" is getting generated which take 4,5 seconds and then the constructor of SignUpComponent is called. All the above mentioned component StepOne,StepTwo & StepThree all extends the Signupcomponent.   

Yes, All the other Modules components are imports, declare in the frontend.module.ts file and in the app.module.ts file frontend.module is declare and import

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and found a native way to resolve it with [PreloadAllModules](https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules#preloading) class from the [@Angular/router](https://angular.io/api/router) library. to do this, just configure your app-routing.module.ts file like this:

```
import { Routes, RouterModule, PreloadAllModules } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
// app globals routes
]

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
    preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules
})],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})

export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

In addition to the [Angular official doc](https://angular.io/api/router/PreloadAllModules#description) I found this excellent [article](https://medium.com/@prowe214/lazy-loading-vs-preloading-modules-which-should-you-choose-85a1fb71a24) which could explain you more about this implementation

Hope that this could help you

Answer (score 0):

If you feel that your app is getting slower due to large number of components . You might need to try lazy loading in Angular.

[**Lazy loading in Action**](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/ngrx/rxjs)

The above is a small lazy loaded component i have developed for my App.

> Lazy loading modules helps us decrease the startup time. With lazy
>   loading our application does not need to load everything at once, it
>   only needs to load what the user expects to see when the app first
>   loads. Modules that are lazily loaded will only be loaded when the
>   user navigates to their routes.

More indepth of how to use Lazy loading 
Credits - https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/modules/lazy-loading-module.html

Comment: Hi, thanks for the solution with demo. But about the lazy loading module. I have already implemented in in app.routing.module.ts file where my each submodules are loaded when user requested that route. But here the problem is when user request signup for the first time it gets slow, as there are multiple component. Should I have to convert all that subcomponent to module???

Answer (score 0):

First attach your signup routing file.
sometes the route guards makes a component load slow.
If there is any guard in the signup routing file then check by removing it

Answer (score -3):

User lazy loading https://angular.io/guide/router#lazy-loading-route-configuration
and your signup component is kind of mess try KISS (keep it simple stupid)

Comment: Agree to try KISS, but my signup has multiple steps used for the user register and apart from signup there is account module which has multiple subcomponent. May be in future there are other module which has more subcomponent then in that case situation differs. So, still if there is something to keep it simple then please let me know what refactoring is required over here.